# Adding links to <td>

Tags: html, html-table

Can't figure out the appropriate way for adding links to `<td>`, I have tried conventional `<a href"#"></a>`, but for some reason messes up the table and messes the CSS.

I have looked at other ways such as `div`, but I am not sure how to implement it.

```
<div id="fftime">
    <table id="ff" class="ffstyle">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Monday</th>
                <th>Tuesday</th>
                <th>Wednesday</th>
                <th>Thursday</th>
                <th>Friday</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>07:00&nbsp;- 08:00</td>
                <td rowspan="5">Sprint Training</td>
                <td>Sparring</td>
                <td rowspan="5">Class 1</td>
                <td rowspan="5">Class 2</td>
                <td rowspan="5">Class 3</td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to put a link inside a `<td>` element, you just need to *put a link inside a `<td>` element*, like so:

```
<td><a href="#">MY TEXT</a></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works totally fine

```
<table id="ff" class="ffstyle">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Monday</th>
            <th>Tuesday</th>
            <th>Wednesday</th>
            <th>Thursday</th>
            <th>Friday</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>07:00&nbsp;- 08:00</td>
            <td rowspan="5"><a href="#">Sprint Training</a></td>
            <td><a href="#">Sparring</a></td>
            <td rowspan="5"><a href="#">Class 1</a></td>
            <td rowspan="5"><a href="#">Class 2</a></td>
            <td rowspan="5"><a href="#">Class 3</a></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thankyou. I was thinking i had to put it elsewhere. you guys are awesome